# How to change thickness of layer by z axis

Tags: swift, animation, 3d, layer

I'm doing animations for UILabel with rotation. And I realize that both rotate and flip produce a same look on screen. Here is my rotation code:

```
let labelLayer = self.label.layer
var labelTransform : CATransform3D = CATransform3DIdentity
labelTransform.m34 = 1.0 / -500.0
labelTransform = CATransform3DRotate(labelTransform, CGFloat(Double.pi), 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: {
    labelLayer.transform = labelTransform
}) { (result) in
    // do nothing  
}
```

To differentiate these animations, I want to make the layer thicker in z-axis for rotate animation. So, any idea how to do that ?

Comment: Did you solve it by chance?